# Please explain the meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence

Please explain to me the meaning of the following sentence:

> I hope such readers will be persuaded that the profundity and value of these ideas more than repay the intellectual struggle they require [...].

Comment: Please provide more context and/or a link to the quoted sentence.  Specifically, ""such readers" clearly refers *back* to something mentioned previously, and we cannot interpret that without the earlier context.  And there is more text missing at the end "... they require [in order to do what?]

Comment: Furthermore, to add to what @TrevorD said, you should make clear what you don't understand in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

```
I hope such readers will be persuaded 
  that 
  the profundity and value of these ideas more than repay
   the intellectual struggle they require
```

I hope such readers will reach the opinion  that  the deep significance and value of these ideas do reward   the arduous mental effort they demand (of the reader).

Comment: I don't see how formatting the sentence like that explains it's meaning, please clarify.

Comment: Since you didn't say what was giving you trouble, I broke it up into meaningful chunks in case you were thinking that an intellectual was being repaid, or some other misparsing.  Did you read the sentence below?

Comment: I see, maybe it would be clearer if broke the second sentence up in a similar fashion? I hadn't realised you interchanged some of the words to make it easier to understand. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd rewrite that sentence into simpler sentences:

I hope you've been persuaded that these ideas are worth learning. They require a good amount of intellectual struggle – you might have to think a lot to understand them. However, they are profound and valuable enough to outweigh that intellectual struggle.

Comment: This a good paraphrase.  I'd consider letting the parenthetical statement stand as a sentence on par with the others. For example: "You may indeed have to think a lot to understand them."  My rationale for that is that although you've simplified the original you've also introduced a complexity that wasn't there at first―the abbreviated Latin phrase *id est*, which may be unfamiliar, or less straightforward, to some readers.